# how to generate rgb color dynamically for created div

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<input type="text" class="ins">

<button class="bts">Click here</button>

<div class="container">

</div>
```

I will type a number in the text box, then after clicking the button I want to generate multiple `div`s. I want to set the `background-color` for the first `div` to **red**, the next one **green**, the next one **blue**, and again **red,green,blue** and so on, if it is possible in JQuery.

// script i am using is:

```
 $(".bts").click(function(){
        var s = $(".ins").val();        

        var shade = 0;

        for(i=0; i < s; i++)
        {   
          $(".container").append('<div class="mydiv"> ok </div>').find(".mydiv").css("background-color", "red");
         }
    });
```

Comment: your question is unclear..do u want to change color to the number you entered in textbox?

Comment: for the empty div "<div class="mydiv"> ok </div>" which is created depending on the number given in the text box

Comment: You want that div to have 1/3 of red, 1/3 of green and 1/3 of blue? Or you want to set ONE color with RGB color option?

Comment: Now I get what you want, by seeing the answers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    currentColor = 0,
    shade = 0;
$(".bts").click(function(){
    var s = $(".ins").val();    

    for(i=0; i < s; i++) {   
        if(currentColor == colors.length) currentColor = 0;
        $('<div class="mydiv"> ok </div>').appendTo('.container').css("background-color", colors[currentColor]);
        currentColor += 1;
     }
});
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2smzk5m/1/

If you want to add more colors, simply add them to the colors array.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bts").click(function(){
    var s = $(".ins").val();        

    $(".container").html("");
    for (i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 1)
            $(".container").append('<div class="reddiv">RED</div>');
        else if (i % 3 == 2)
            $(".container").append('<div class="greendiv">GREEN</div>');
        else
            $(".container").append('<div class="bluediv">BLUE</div>');
        $(".reddiv,.greendiv,.bluediv").css("padding", "5px").css("margin", "5px"); 
        $(".reddiv").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".greendiv").css("background-color", "green");
        $(".bluediv").css("background-color", "blue");
    }
    });
});
```

Also see same at **[Hear](https://jsfiddle.net/saddam_msp/Lc7ygw94/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Dear i thought you want set background color randomly.
Please see it tested code on my browser.
for exm- you input in input box (4,2,8..etc) then button is showing with random 
background.**

```
           $(".bts").click(function() {
                var s = $(".ins").val();
                var shade = 0, tempColorArr = [];
                tempColorArr = genrateRGB(s);

                for ( i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                    $(".container").append('<div class="mydiv" style="background-color:'+ tempColorArr[i]+'"> ok </div>');
                }
            });

            function genrateRGB(tempVal) {
                var colorArr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < tempVal; i++) {
                    colorArr[i] = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                }
                return colorArr;
            }
```

See this link-
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f25rubc8e